# Do i need to add the function AntiForgery.GetHtml() in all of the web pages that i create?

Tags: .net, asp.net-webpages, antiforgerytoken

I am developing an ASP.NET Web Pages application. I see that the default Web Page application created in Visual Studio includes the function call to AntiForgery.GetHtml(). I studied and understood the functionality if this call and the AntiForgery.Validate() call as well. But now my question that should i include this function call in all of the Web Pages that i create? Even if i do add the AntiForgery.GetHtml() in my _Layout.cshtml file i have to add the second function to validate the page in all of my content pages. Please let me know the right way to do this and the reason why need to do it a certain way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer for this question on another forum. The answer is simple, the AntiForgery.GetHtml() and AntiForgery.Validate() functions should be made use of in only those web pages that have a form data that will eventually be submitted by a user during post back.

Below is the link to the original answer.

http://forums.asp.net/t/2024282.aspx?Do+i+need+to+add+the+function+AntiForgery+GetHtml+in+all+of+the+web+pages+that+i+create+

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that function inside Page_Init event 
if (IsPostBack)

in the master page

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not the usual ASP.NET Web Forms application. The one that i'm developing is an ASP.NET Web Pages application.

Comment: Do You have master Page in Your application?

Comment: No. The concept of Master Page exists only in ASP.NET Web Forms Application. I am developing a ASP.NET Web Pages Application.

Answer (score 0):

How about placing an 'index.html' in every folder
on your site and including.....`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://MY HOME PAGE">
<title>ACCESS DENIED</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>ACCESS DENIED</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it's not asp but it will keep people out of your folders if that's what you want to do.

Comment: I am not sure if the above idea would work, but if ASP.NET Web Pages library offers me an inbuilt function to check forgery then i guess it must be the most appropriate way to do it.

Comment: No it wouldn't work once a form has been sent, I assume you've seen this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175.aspx

Comment: The above link you posted points to a method that is used in case of MVC patterns of ASP.NET Web Application. I am developing a plain ASP.NET Web Pages Application which does not use a pattern such as MVC. It's more similar to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write it inside HTTP Module
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx